# Starting/Stopping Ajax call via Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, setinterval

I have a web page with 2 tabs. These tabs show/hide divs when clicked. Both tabs use jquery to make an ajax call to a php script to display results from a different database. So tab 1 shows a list of food and the second tab shows a list of prices. Its set to refresh automatically every 30 seconds. My question is when I click between the 2 tabs I prefer the tab not clicked stops the ajax call so only the one ajax call is running, basically for optimization purposes. How would I go about doing this? Would I use setInterval to have it run the first tab ajax call every 30 seconds then when the other tab is clicked a function is called to run clearInterval on the id the first setinterval was running? Then visa versa if the first tab is clicked it clears the interval for the second tab ajax call?

Comment: What are you using for the tabbing--jQ UI tabs?

Comment: @JAAulde Yes I am using UI tabs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basicly there is no reason for what you are doing.

I would prefer, if you have something to load, that needs to be loaded after some time, you should call for both tabs, but only ask, if something changed. So let´s say, you call the server every 10 seconds if something changed, returning false or true is not such a huge thing, and if returned yes, just synchronize both items.

if there is no need to sync both items, why you just dont sync them when the tab is clicked?

For user experience it´s better to ask for changes often, but syncing the content only if needed.

And if you do this all, don´t use setInterval but setTimeout and in you function call the setTimeout again, setInterval is not so good ;-)

Comment: Both tabs dont have any relations to each other. Both grab records from different tables in the database for different things. One tab could have a 100 listings, one tab could have just 5. I thought by stopping the ajax call for the inactive tab and only have the one tab being viewed would save on resources. Because its not querying the database in the inactive tab, so I was assuming it would run faster, especially if multiple people are looking at the same page.

Comment: especially if there are 100 items or more i would prefer to "ask" if there is anything to change. Even for two tabs. Imagine gmail would everytime load all emails in the current view completely new, even if there is nothing new...

Comment: So to clarify, you suggest to run the ajax script when the page first loads to populate both tables, then the ajax calls checks to see if there are updates. If so then update the tab with the new information otherwise dont do anything? Since there are multiple fields that could be updated would you recommend a separate table that tracks updates and check that table to see if an update needs to happen instead of quering the table with all the data directly?

Comment: there are more options. i use the "latest" method. with your ajax request, where you recieve all your new data, pass in the date and time of your latest item, or the id if increamental. If there are updates in existing rows you should consider the update on tab change, that´s easier than tracking changes in db.

Comment: well I was thinking if the table itself grew to hundreds of thousands of rows if not more, it would be faster to just initially query a table that may have 10-20 rows if there was an update. Or do you think that shouldnt be an issue?

Answer (score 0):

Pulling repeatedly versus pulling when something is new is a decent discussion, but I'll stay away from it for now.

jQuery UI tabs has ways to bind behavior on tab change. I would wire it up such that when a tab becomes visible, it is filled with server content and the interval is started to repeat that behavior. I'd store the return of jQuery's AJAX function (the XHR itself on older jQ, a jQ XHR wrapper in 1.5) and the returned timer ID which resulted from starting the interval.

Then, whenever a new tab loaded, I'd call abort() on the XHR/wrapper and clearInterval on the timer ID, then do the same thing I did for the previous tab in the new one--fill via AJAX (storing the XHR) and start the interval (storing the ID).